# GIF from external resource in page is not animating in apache wicket web application

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket, gif, wicket-6

I am using external images in my webaplication, everything wass fine until I wanted to add animated gif there, the gif loads, but it doesn't animate.

Java code:

```
    File sourceimage = new File("loading_img.gif");

    try {
        final BufferedDynamicImageResource r = new BufferedDynamicImageResource("GIF");
        r.setImage(ImageIO.read(sourceimage));
        add(new Image("gif",  r));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

HTML:

```
                <img wicket:id="gif"/>
```

EDIT:

Tried martin-g suggestion, gif still doesn't animate

```
      try {
          final BufferedDynamicImageResource r = new BufferedDynamicImageResource("GIF"){
              @Override
              protected void setResponseHeaders(AbstractResource.ResourceResponse data,
                      IResource.Attributes attributes){
                  super.setResponseHeaders(data, attributes);
                  data.setContentType("image/gif");
              }
              };
          r.setImage(ImageIO.read(sourceimage));
          add(new Image("gif",  r));

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the content type is not automatically set.
You will need to override org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource#setResponseHeaders() and set with via `resourceResponse.setContentType(String)`.

Maybe this should be done automatically by Wicket in org.apache.wicket.request.resource.DynamicImageResource, since it knows the format ("png", or "gif" as in your case). Please file a ticket in Wicket's JIRA for this improvement! Thanks!

Comment: I've said "you need to override `AbstractResource#setResponseHeaders()` and inside it call `resourceResponse.setContentType(String)`

Comment: The problem is that to do that I need to create a subclass which extends AbstractResource. Nowhere in the code do I call nor mention AbstractResource, therefore I won't be able to call my class with overriden method setResponseHeaders().

Comment: BufferedDynamicImageResource is a specialization of AbstractResource. You need to override its `#setResponseHeaders()`

Comment: overrided it with                 
super.setResponseHeaders(data, attributes);
data.setContentType("image/gif");

Gif still doesn't animate.

Comment: Maybe the issue is here: ImageIO.read(sourceimage) - this loads only images not gifs?

Comment: Did you check that its content type is correct in the browser dev tools ?

Comment: Not sure how can I check that, there is no mention of img/gif in html, also when I download the image from the deployed site it's also not moving.

Comment: It's content type is: "image/gif"